# Force float:right?

Tags: html, css

I have a custom html box within Joomla with the following

```html
<span style="color: #FFFFFF; font-size: 1em; padding-top:5px;">

<p style="float: right; display: inline-block; white-space: nowrap; margin-bottom: 5px;"><img src="/images/telephone_call_contact.png"> 0000000000</p>
<br>
<p style="float: right; display: inline-block; white-space: nowrap;"><img src="/images/email_envelope.png"> contact@email.co.uk</p>
<br>
<p style="float: right; display: inline-block; white-space: nowrap;"><img src="/images/shop_open.png"> Open 7 Days 5:00pm-11:00pm </p>
</span>
```

This works fine. However, when the browser is resized down to a certain level one will come undone until you resize even further.

Similarly, at another dimension they'll also not align properly.

[image: Normal]

[image: Broken]

[image: Also out of alignment]

Does anyone know why this behaviour is occurring?

EDIT: As Antonio suggested, adding clear:both to p in the CSS partially resolved this issue. Now the issue occurs only on the first line (when it didn't before)

Comment: The images don't load. 
Could you load the correct images.

Comment: @AnkurAnand They load fine for me.

Comment: They don't load for me in the snippet. 
Also the images have relative path, so I am not sure how they would load properly.

Comment: @jblz You have problems in ur markup. please consider my answer for a good solution

Comment: consider using flexbox if you don't require ancient browser support - http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox

Comment: @Trix I would, but I edited the post advising Antonios comment partially fixed the issue, and caused the same issue to occur on another line

Comment: Whats the problem with mine?

Comment: Embarrassingly, I'm not sure how to turn that into an inline statement (mainly the images). Apologies, I missed your reply before.

Answer (score 2):

Add `clear:both` to your `p` css rules

[example](http://codepen.io/Ayeetu/pen/ZGodJL).

Comment: Fantastic, thanks. Why did this work? Unfortunately this is still broken in the third example, but is now on the first line of text instead of the third

Comment: Just find some tutorials on the web about floats and clearing i'm sure there are alot of them out there that will explain it in detail more than i can in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

I think that adding a `clear:right` should solve your issue, but I can't be so sure as the images in your snippet do not load.

```html
<span style="color: #FFFFFF; font-size: 1em; padding-top:5px;">

<p style="float: right; display: inline-block; white-space: nowrap; margin-bottom: 5px;"><img src="/images/telephone_call_contact.png"> 0000000000</p>
<br>
<p style="float: right; display: inline-block; white-space: nowrap;clear:right;"><img src="/images/email_envelope.png"> contact@email.co.uk</p>
<br>
<p style="float: right; display: inline-block; white-space: nowrap;clear:right;
"><img src="/images/shop_open.png"> Open 7 Days 5:00pm-11:00pm </p>
</span>
```

Comment: `<p>` is not valid inside `<span>`.  It's likely that browsers will close the span before the first 'graph.

Answer (score 0):

You would better forget using inline styles for your markup, as it has SEO downsides. instead use an external stylesheet.
Also, your markup has some problems, so you'd better do it like this:

```css
.details{
  text-align: right;
  background-color: #744C27;
}
.details span{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 1em;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.icons{
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.phone{ background-image: url( 'images/telephone_call_contact.png' ) }
.email{ background-image: url( 'images/email_envelope.png' ) }
.shop{ background-image: url( 'images/shop_open.png' ) }
```

```html
<div class="details">
  <div><span class="icons phone"></span><span>0000000000</span></div>
  <div><span class="icons email"></span><span>contact@email.co.uk</span></div>
  <div><span class="icons shop"></span><span>Open 7 Days 5:00pm-11:00pm</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: While I appreciate the comment, I'm working with custom html modules within Joomla. The reason I'm not adding rules to the CSS file is to keep it as modular as possible.

Comment: Thats ok, but you may keep the above markup as it wont breakup like images provided. Just add styles to the flements